# Alert after all checkboxes have been checked

Tags: jquery

i have looked everywhere(but maybe i've missed something)

I'm currently creating a website where people have 3 options.

Let's do it easy, 1,2 and 3.

Now the customer wants a technique that after you clicked the third checkbox(doesn't matter in which way, you can go from 1 to 3 and then 2, or 3,1 and then 2) a alert popup comes up.

Now i have looked everywhere but i can't find it.
Hopefully someone inhere could help me.

Thanx already.

Comment: Your question being .. ?

Comment: @yoda: "define your question, you must!" ...sorry. I couldn't resist... =/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work, I think:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(
    function(){
        if ($('input:checkbox:checked').length == $('input:checkbox').length){
            alert('All checkboxes are checked!');
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XtgZf/1/).

---

**Edited** in response to mblase75's (accurate) comment (below):

> Of course this won't work if there are ANY other checkboxes on the page, but that can easily be solved by adding a class to the three checkboxes being monitored and selecting that instead.

The above can be easily adapted to apply to the children of a single element, regardless of how many of those elements are on the page:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(

function() {
    var $formElement = $(this).closest('form');
    if($formElement.find('input:checkbox:checked').length == $formElement.find('input:checkbox').length) {
        alert('All checkboxes are checked!');
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XtgZf/6/).

Amending the `$formElement = $(this).closest('form');` variable assignment to select another element, `div`, `fieldset` or, well, any *other* element, would allow you to target only those checkboxes within that given element.

References:

- [`:checkbox` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)
- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/)
- [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)
- [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length)
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: Of course this won't work if there are ANY other checkboxes on the page, but that can easily be solved by adding a class to the three checkboxes being monitored and selecting that instead.

Comment: @mblase75, you're right (of course..!), I was editing an adaptation in when you commented, then it didn't seem right not to acknowledge your comment...so! Amended to be form-specific.

Comment: @JoelAlejandro: thank you kindly! I figured it was better that way...and it's somewhat easier to write that way too. So...win-win! =)

Comment: @David Thomas Your example worked perfect for my need. Here's a small adaptation of your suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/rzea/Fdc5Q/1/ - Tnx! BTW, I updated `input:checkbox` to `input[type=checkbox]` since the first is already deprecated in jQuery 1.8 - http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#cb1,#cb2,#cb3").change(function() {
    if ($("#cb1").prop("checked") && $("#cb2").prop("checked") && $("#cb3").prop("checked")) {
        alert("all three checked");
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
$('.yourchexkoboxes').click(function(){
   var $chkboxs = $('.yourchexkoboxes').length;
   var $CheckedChkboxs = $('.yourchexkoboxes:checked').length;
   if($chkboxs  === $CheckedChkboxs){
        //all checkobexes have been checked
   }
});
```